# background repeat not working with sass and foundation 5

Tags: sass, mixins, repeat, zurb-foundation-5

I am currently working with SASS(SCSS) and foundation 5 frame work.

I am trying to get the background image to pull via a mixin which is working but for some reason I cannot get the "repeat" CSS function to work properly. All the other CSS functions work fine.

```
    @mixin cover-background($img-uri, $background-top:"center", $repeat:"repeat", $background-left:"center", $background-attachment:"fixed") {
    background: url($img-uri) unquote($repeat) unquote($background-top) unquote($background-left) unquote($background-attachment); 

   }

   body{
       @include cover-background('http://IMAGE.png');
   }
```

For some reason the image pulls just fine and it centers it but will not repeat it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out what was happening.

I had

```
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
```

Which was overriding the repeat. Sorry guys.